# What does the phrase “to purse your lips” mean？

Tags: meaning, expressions

My mother tongue isn't English, my English teacher asked me to find out the meaning of the phrase

> "to purse your lips"

Comment: Welcome! Your first stop should be an online dictionary such as dictionary.com. You can then check Google for images of people with pursed lips.

Comment: You might find the community for [ell.se] helpful, too (although they would also want you to consult a dictionary first).

Answer (score 2):

The expression derives from the original sense of the  term [purse](https://www.etymonline.com/word/purse):

> "little bag made of leather," especially for carrying money, from Medieval Latin bursa "leather purse"

used in  the  following connotation of the verb ***to purse:***

> c. 1600 as "draw together and wrinkle" (as the strings of a money bag), from purse (n.)

from which:

> if you pucker or contract your lips, you're pursing them.

Answer (score 0):

purse your lips

to press your lips together and outwards because you are angry or are
thinking Martha pursed her lips disapprovingly.

[Purse your lips](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/purse_2)