# What is the word or phrase to describe the action of pursing one's lips in a tight rounded shape in a happy mood?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

As the title says, what is the word or phrase to describe the action of pursing one's lips in a tight **rounded shape** in a **happy** mood?

[Merriam-Webster: purse(verb)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/purse) defines it as (quoting from English Language Learners):

> to form (your lips) into a tight **circle** or **line**

So "purse one's lips" can mean forming a line instead of a circle.

[Cambridge Dictionary: purse(verb)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/purse) defines it as follows:

> to bring your lips tightly together so that they form a rounded shape, usually as an expression of **disapproval**
>
> Example: "I don't approve of that kind of language," she said, pursing her lips.

So "purse one's lips" usually shows the feeling of disapproval (although I think it can also mean a happy mood).

But I'm trying to find a word or a phrase that **specifically** refers to "rounded shape" and "happy mood". **For example**, "So happy to see her boyfriend again, she ___ her lips to ask for a kiss from him." From our life experience we know that, in this example, when she "___" her lips, the lips don't form a line but a circle, and she must be in a happy mood.

I'm aware of [this question *What does the phrase "to purse your lips" mean？ [closed]*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/463506/7342) but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: To draw up your lips to imply/request a kiss is to [pucker up](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pucker-up). Pursing one's lips doesn't imply a happy mood in any other context - usually disapproval or thinking hard about something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Pucker**

> to tighten skin or cloth until small folds appear or (of skin or cloth) to form small folds

*He puckered his lips and kissed her.*

[Cambridge Dictionary]

> **Pucker** is a verb for what happens when something smooth or flat gets folded up into little wrinkles, like how you pucker your lips when you go to kiss someone — you, wild flirt, you!

[Vocabulary.com]